# quartz scheduler triggering automatically when system date is changed

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net

i am using Quartz.dll in a windows service to trigger some web services at some specified intervals.

for some testing purpose i have manually changed  the date to tomorrow which is automatically triggering some web services.

ex:- I have a trigger set up which runs at 12:30 a.m every day and i am changing  the date manually today (7/1/2014) at 06:30 a.m to tomorrows date, so the system time now in 8/1/2014 06:30:00. a.m. the trigger which was supposed to be triggered at 12:30 a.m. on 8th Jan is getting triggered automatically.

Is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that when you change the system date, quartz realizes that it has missed the job that should have been triggered at 12:30am on 7/1/2014 and will therefore fire off that job immediately.

Comment: Good guess. Even though manually changing the system date is not realistic scenario in production environment is there any way i can avoid this from happening without stopping the service...

Comment: Quartz is only aware that it has missed it's fire time, it does not know why this occurred. For example the system might have been down for 24 hours. Look at the quartz misfire instructions in order to tell the scheduler what to do if it misses its fire time. a good article explaining quartz misfire instructions can be found [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/quartz-scheduler-misfire).